# Releasing using Maven when trunk only should contain release versions

Tags: maven, svn, configuration-management

Normally `mvn:release prepare` will (amongst other things)

- Update the artifact version to the release version and commit
- Branch to a tag from the release version
- Update the artifact version to the next SNAPSHOT version and commit

It has worked fine. However, we have a new way of working:

- All development is done in our `branches/features` branch
- `trunk` must only have release versions

We would like releasing to work as follows:

1. We work in `features`
2. After a release a merge from `features` to `trunk` should have been done. Nothing in `trunk` should be saved, that will not be a problem as no work should be done there. In other words, at the point of release trunk should mirror the release version
3. A tag from `trunk` should have been made

It will look like this in SVN: (R = Release version, S = SNAPSHOT version)

```
         1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
         |
         |        1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
         |        |
         |        |    1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
         |        |    |
         |        |    |           1.0.4-SNAPSHOT
         |        |    |           |
         | : :    |    | : : : :   |

features S-S-S-R--S--R-S-S-S-S-S-R-S->

               |     |           |
              \|/   \|/         \|/
               V     V           V

trunk    ------R-----R-----------R--->

               |     |           |
              \|/   \|/         \|/
               V     V           V

tag      ------R-----R-----------R--->

               |     |           |
               |     |           |
               1.0.1 |           1.0.3
                     |
                     1.0.2
```

- How can this be done?
- Can/Should this be done with the release plugin alone? We already use that plugin so it would be nice.
- Can/Should it be done using any other standard plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems the release plugin is close to what you want to do? I'm not sure what you question is?

What hits the eye is that there seems to be a bit of an ambiguity what is in trunk and what should not be there. You need to be careful not to start fighting maven:

"-SNAPSHOT" indicates a working version - I know you know that :)

Since you work on feature branches and merge into trunk that will be the working version. Since here you need to integrate all features and verify they work together. That's why trunk will have a SNAPSHOT version.

Once this is done you use the release plugin to tag / branch from here.

Since trunk must reflect what you actually delivered (the stable branch, so to say). I would argue that creating an interim-branch may help keeping things clear: you could create a "developmen" Branch used to integrate the feature Branches. Once that is ok, merge those changes into your trunk.

Mainly you would follow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
(possible with SVN too, if using SVN applies here)

Please be aware that feature branches have some drawbacks too: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html

There is a 3 episodes video from [Neil Ford](https://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/conference/speaker/neal_ford). In [Episode 2](https://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/topics/continuous_delivery_workshop_part_2_of_3_testing_synergistic_practices_and_deployment) he gives some alternatives to Feature Branches.

Back to maven: you need to have a SNAPSHOT Version on your trunk, the release plugin will not like anything else. The only thing in a repo without SNAPSHOT are on Tags. Those versions are fixed. Any maintenance Branch will also have a SNAPSHOT version (a unique one). Feature Branches Usually share the version with their target branch they will get merge into. Note: the CI server should not "mvn deploy" or "mvn install" feature branches into a common shared repository.